# HTTP Load test with Golang

Tags: go, concurrency, http

I am a golang novice... I am trying to write an application that takes in many requests - up to a sustained 10000 HTTP posts/sec and post the payload to two back-ends in parallel (5 second timeout).  A canned message is returned to the client, it doesn't matter whether the backed end returns a response or errors out, the same response text is sent to the client.

I have a first crack at it below.  I'm not worried about error handling yet.  My thinking is that I can make each back-end call asynchronous using goroutines and let the go runtime deal with queuing/threads for the go routines.  I simply need to perform the post and log the result, there is no communication between goroutines. I have had others guide me to using channels, but given that I don't need to return any data back from the post I'm not sure I need them.

Here is my first very simple crack at it.  Please make any suggestions on the code and approach!

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/go-chi/chi"
    "net/http"
    "io/ioutil"
    "bytes"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    r := chi.NewRouter()
    r.Post("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        handlePost(w, r);
    })

    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", r)

}

func handlePost(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "dummy response will go here");
    go callBackend("http://backend1", body)
    go callBackend("http://backend2", body)
}

func callBackend(url string, body []byte) {

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(body))
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/xml")

    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout: time.Second * 5,
    }
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    fmt.Sprintf("backend [%s] response status: %s", url, resp.Status)
    fmt.Println("backend response Headers:", resp.Header)
    responsebody, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Println("backend response Body:", string(responsebody))

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
r.Post("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    handlePost(w, r)
})
```

can be simplified to

```
r.Post("/", handlePost)
```

since both functions have same signature.

---

```
fmt.Fprintf(w, "dummy response will go here")
```

No need to use `printf` family functions where you don't need formatting. You can write directly with

```
w.Write([]byte("dummy response will go here"))
```

or with

```
io.WriteString(w, "dummy response will go here")
```

---

```
responsebody, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
fmt.Println("backend response Body:", string(responsebody))
```

This one reads the whole response into memory for no reason. Use `io.Copy` to write it more efficiently:

```
fmt.Print("backend response Body: ")
_, err := io.Copy(os.Stdout, resp.Body)
```

---

> I'm not worried about error handling yet.

Then everything else is totally fine.